# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_cart() on null in plugins/custom/index.php:131

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to do add to cart programmatically in woocommerce, this take place when contact form 7 is get submitted.

I added add to cart function in `wpcf7_before_send_mail` hook, but `WC()->cart` is null inside this function, why is this?

I am getting the following error:

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_cart() on null in /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/custom/index.php:131
```

Stack trace:

```
#0 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/custom/index.php(72): add_product_to_cart()
#1 /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(288):
```

The code is:

```
wpcf7_do_something(Object(WPCF7_ContactForm))

add_action("wpcf7_before_send_mail", "wpcf7_do_something");

function wpcf7_do_something (&$WPCF7_ContactForm) {

     $category =  $_POST['Category'];
     $fname =  $_POST['Fname'];
     $lname =  $_POST['Lname'];
     $email =  $_POST['email'];
     $Mobile =  $_POST['Mobile'];
     $address1 =  $_POST['address1'];
     $address2 =  $_POST['address2'];
     $city =  $_POST['city'];
     $pincode =  $_POST['pincode'];
     $country =  $_POST['country'];

     /* add user to db start*/
     $username = $fname;
     $password = 'pasword123';
     if (username_exists($fname) == null && email_exists($email) == false) {
         // Create the new user
        $user_id = wp_create_user( $username, $password, $email );

        // Get current user object
        $user = get_user_by( 'id', $user_id );
      }else{
        $user = get_user_by( 'email', $email );
        $user_id = $user->ID;
      }
      if ( empty( $user ) ){
        $user = get_user_by( 'login', $username );
        $user_id = $user->ID;
      }
    /* add user to db end*/

  add_product_to_cart();
}
 function add_product_to_cart() {
  if ( ! is_admin() ) {
    $product_id = 455; //replace with your own product id
    $found = false;

    error_reporting(E_ALL);
          ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    //check if product already in cart
    if ( sizeof( WC()->cart->get_cart() ) > 0 ) {
      foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
        $_product = $values['data'];
        if ( $_product->get_id() == $product_id )
          $found = true;
      }
      // if product not found, add it
      if ( ! $found )
        WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id );
    } else {
      // if no products in cart, add it
      WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: From what i can see now, you should comment the first line, the one before add_action. Maybe it is the cause of the error, as it is run before WooCommerce is loaded.

Comment: even removing above line also, getting same error

Answer (score 0):

Try :
global $woocommerce;
$woocommerce->cart->get_cart();

Comment: Getting below error on adding  
global $woocommerce;$woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_cart() on null

Comment: Add your code in if condition and check whether it is executed. 

   if ( class_exists( 'WooCommerce' ) ) {
         echo "test";
        // code that requires WooCommerce access
   } else {
       // you don't appear to have WooCommerce plugin access
   }